# Adding multiple lines in registry

Tags: windows, string, registry

I have an application that I use frequently on multiple machines. I would like to export the registry settings that I normally have to configure on each machine so I can script them to be imported at startup. The application allows me to put multiple lines of text into a text box, which will overlay that text on all printouts. It saves that text in a string in the registry. When I export the registry, the string looks something like this:

```
"sEndorsement"="Line 1 of text
Line 2 of Text"
```

This doesn't import properly because of the break in the string. Any ideas how to make that import nicely? I don't really have the option to just use one line of text in the settings.

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: Exporting a file from windows does not import properly back to windows.  That's weird:/.  I notice, you can export using different file formats, have you tried exporting using each different formats then importing?  Just a suggestion.  One of them might import properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the standard .reg file you got from exporting the settings, you'll have to do it via VBScript, using `vbCrLf` to introduce the newlines in your string.

```
set ShellObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ShellObj.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Key\sEndorsement", "Line1" & vbCrLf & "Line2", "REG_SZ"
```

Comment: Thant makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately the registry change needs to be made via a GPO without running a script. It looks like I may be SOL :/

Comment: I'm no expert in this area, but I think there are ways to set up logon script GPOs...

Answer (score 0):

another approach assuming the app and its code is yours is to use a .ini file or other text file to save and load the settings from a standard place like %user-folder%\your-app-name\settings.txt

Answer (score 0):

If the first line (or only line) of the **key=value** always starts with a double-quote, then your import code could detect that. Pseudo-code:

```
firstLine   = TRUE
keyAndValue = NULL
for each line to import
    line = get line
    if line[0] == '"' then
        if have previous line
            import keyAndValue
        keyAndValue = line
    else
        keyAndValue = concat(keyAndValue, CRLF, line)
end for
if keyAndValue is not NULL
    import keyAndValue
```

As said before, this could be implemented in VBScript -- or Perl for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one Python Script, using [_winreg](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) module. Some snippets:

```
from _winreg import *

#read Data:
key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'Software\MyCompany\MyApp', 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
value_data = QueryValueEx(key, "MyValueName")[0]

#write data:
key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'Software\MyCompany\MyApp', 0, KEY_WRITE)
SetValueEx(key, "MyValueName", 0, REG_SZ, "MyValueData")
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use VBScript by using `vbCrLf` with the [RegWrite function](http://ss64.com/vb/regwrite.html).

Alternatively, and I'm not sure if this is possible within the context of your problem, change the registry key type to `REG_MULTI_SZ` instead of `REG_SZ`.

`REG_MULTI_SZ` strings are null-terminated as such:

```
String 1\0String2\0String3\0
```

And you can walk through them after reading the registry and just join them with newlines in your app.

[MSDN has a good description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of how these work and a code sample.